# Encountering an error while calling a non built-in function in R

Tags: r, function, date, error-handling

I made a function in R which basically takes certain values from a column of my dataframe according to the dates specified and returns their sum:

```
 <<>>=
    dmon.function = function(y, m, d){
      result = sum(dmystatedf$Deceased[Dategood>="y-m-01" & Dategood<="y-m-d"])
    }
    dmon.function(2021, 04, 03)
    @
```

Now when I pass the function, I get no error, but when I call the function, I get this error:

```
> dmon.function(2021, 04, 03)
 Error in charToDate(x) : 
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

How do I resolve this error? How to I make functions that takes arguments and use them as dates, months, or years in general?

**EDIT 1:** Here are the first few rows of the data I'm using:

```
> head(dmystatedf[c("Deceased", "Dategood")])
    Deceased   Dategood
61         0 2020-03-09
74         0 2020-03-10
87         0 2020-03-11
101        0 2020-03-12
115        1 2020-03-13
130        1 2020-03-14
```

Here is the output of the code `dput(head(dmystatedf[c("Deceased", "Dategood")]))` as requested by Rui Barradas in comments:

```
> dput(head(dmystatedf[c("Deceased", "Dategood")]))
structure(list(Deceased = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), Dategood = structure(18330:18335, class = "Date")), row.names = c(61L, 
74L, 87L, 101L, 115L, 130L), class = "data.frame")
```

***THANK YOU***

Comment: @RuiBarradas Sorry, just figured that out and made the edit. But now I have a different error with which I need help.

Comment: Please post a data example. Edit the question with the output of `dput(head(dmystatedf[c("Deceased", "Dategood")]))`, please.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Edited. What I intend to do with my function is that I want it to accept three integers a,b,g as arguments and give output of the sum function applied on the data from date "a-b-01" to "a-b-g". Is the format of the function I used correct? If not, then what would the correct format be?

Comment: You  are comparing a Date object to a string like `"y-m-01"`.  R will not automatically substitute the variables `y` and `m` into the string.  You need to calculate the comparison date in some other way.

Comment: @user2554330 I used lubridate package and kept the argument of function as a string of the standard date format. It works, but it significantly increased the amount of work I had  to do after calling the function. Anyways, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need contributed packages, base R alone is enough to solve the question's problem.
Base function `ISOdate` accepts `year`, `month` and `day` and returns an oject of class `"POSIXt" "POSIXct"`. Then the comparisons to the column of class `"Date"` will give warnings so coerce the start and end dates with `as.Date`.

```r
dmon.function <- function(y, m, d){
  start <- as.Date(ISOdate(y, m, 1))
  end <- as.Date(ISOdate(y, m, d))
  sum(dmystatedf$Deceased[dmystatedf$Dategood >= start & dmystatedf$Dategood <= end])
}

dmon.function(2021, 04, 03)
#> [1] 0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>